# ra-supabase: how to use AutocompleteInput inside of ReferenceInput

Tags: react-admin, supabase

I'm currently having issues trying to get the autocomplete to search properly. I've got a currency table and a country table. The country table has a field called "currency_id".

This is what i currently have:

```
      <ReferenceInput source="currency_id" reference="currency">
        <AutocompleteInput name="currency_id" optionText={"code"} />
      </ReferenceInput>
```

The issue is the request being sent to supabase is the following:
`http://localhost:54321/rest/v1/currency?order=id.desc&offset=0&limit=25&q=eq.ddf`

This is a causing a 400 error from supabase stating that following:
`{"code":"42703","details":null,"hint":null,"message":"column currency.q does not exist"}`

I'm probably being dumb but am i forgetting to do something?
Let me know if you need more information

I’ve used the prop filterToQuery on Autocomplete which fixes it but it still sends `eq` and I can’t seem t figure out how to make it use `like`

**Edit**
**Currency Table SQL**

```
create table "public"."currency" (
    "id" character varying(255) not null default uuid_generate_v4(),
    "name" character varying(255) not null,
    "code" character(3) not null,
    "created_at" timestamp with time zone not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "updated_at" timestamp with time zone not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);


alter table "public"."currency" enable row level security;
alter table "public"."currency" add constraint "idx_17323_primary" PRIMARY KEY using index "idx_17323_primary";
```

**Country Table SQL**

```
create table "public"."country" (
    "id" character varying(255) not null default uuid_generate_v4(),
    "currency_id" character varying(255) not null,
    "name" character varying(255) not null,
    "code_2" character(2) not null,
    "created_at" timestamp with time zone not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "updated_at" timestamp with time zone not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);


alter table "public"."country" enable row level security;
CREATE INDEX idx_17316_fk_9307401d490f6b38540cc3c368b ON public.country USING btree (currency_id);
alter table "public"."country" add constraint "idx_17316_primary" PRIMARY KEY using index "idx_17316_primary";
alter table "public"."country" add constraint "country_currency_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (currency_id) REFERENCES currency(id) not valid;

alter table "public"."country" validate constraint "country_currency_id_fkey";
```

Comment: Can you share the table definition i.e all columns, types, etc for the table `currency` ?

Comment: @Mansueli Yep i've put in my post the sql for both country and currency ope that's enough? Just a bit of context this currently is on a MySQL db. I've migrated everything over to supabase/postgres

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `q` is not a column in the `currency` table:

I am assuming you are trying to use the `code` (3 digits code there). Then you could call it like this if you only want the currency data:

```
http://localhost:54321/rest/v1/currency?select=*&code=eq.CAD&limit=15&order=id.desc
```

If you want also the related rows from the country table, then you could do:

```
/rest/v1/currency?select=*%2Ccountry%28*%29&code=eq.CAD&limit=25&order=id.desc
```

Here is the results from each call respectively:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "ed3d9797-3eb8-41ce-ad1b-aec83cdc55b4",
    "name": "Canadian Dollar",
    "code": "CAD",
    "created_at": "2023-04-12T17:46:36.987366+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2023-04-12T17:46:36.987366+00:00"
  }
]
```

Fetching related records would end up in a nested object:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "ed3d9797-3eb8-41ce-ad1b-aec83cdc55b4",
    "name": "Canadian Dollar",
    "code": "CAD",
    "created_at": "2023-04-12T17:46:36.987366+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2023-04-12T17:46:36.987366+00:00",
    "country": [
      {
        "id": "1ee4a46e-ad30-45b7-acd4-244db981633c",
        "currency_id": "ed3d9797-3eb8-41ce-ad1b-aec83cdc55b4",
        "name": "Canada",
        "code_2": "ca",
        "created_at": "2023-04-12T17:47:34.955108+00:00",
        "updated_at": "2023-04-12T17:47:34.955108+00:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Extra notes:

- You should not use varchar. Postgres recommends using Text instead.
- If you want this case insensitive, then install the CITEXT extension and turn this column into CITEXT datatype.